# maven assembly plugin tgz - no such archiver

Tags: maven

I need to do a really simple tar action using the maven-assembly-plugin.

My file extension must be .tgz not tar.gz

Here is my pom.xml

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
  <build>
  <plugins>

  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>default-cli</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
          <descriptors>
            <descriptor>dist-all.xml</descriptor>
          </descriptors>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
  </plugins>

  </build>


</project>
```

and here is my assembly description file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<assembly>
  <id>default-cli</id>
  <formats>
    <format>tgz</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>src/app</directory>
      <outputDirectory>target</outputDirectory>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

when I run **mvn clean install** it generates the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2.1:single (default-cli) on project my-app: Failed to create assembly: Unable to obtain archiver for extension 'tgz', for assembly: 'default-cli': No such archiver: 'tgz'. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

According to the maven page I am allowed 'tgz' format.

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html

What have I missed?

I'd be grateful for any help,

Comment: Try to update your maven-assembly-plugin which is given in the only reference (3.1.0) instead of 2.2.1..

Comment: No luck I'm afraid. I went up 3.1.0, down to 2.4.1 and 2.3. Still the same. I also tried with a fresh repo directory in my .m2/ folder.

Comment: @khmarbaise i created a brand new directory with those same two files and updated to 3.1.0. This resolved the issue.